# Python read data from XML file

Tags: python, xml, tags, minidom

I use minidom to read my XML files but with the following example this is not working. I have an error message:

I would to retrieve the value in `<span>` tag (`101.86090`) but I have an error.

This is the code:

```
 from xml.dom import minidom

 docXML = minidom.parse('/root/Desktop/tpage.xml')
 node = docXML.getElementsByTagName('span')[0]
 t= node.firstChild.data
```

This is the content of `tpage.xml`:

```
<span class="lp">

<span sys:innerhtml="{binding Last}"

sys:codeafter="$.quotebroker.setTitleProperties($dataItem, 'Last')">


  101.86090

</span>

</span>
```

and this is the error message:

```
 File "minidomrecup.py", line 5, in <module>
    dom = parse('/root/Desktop/bot/tpage.xml')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1920, in parse
    return expatbuilder.parse(file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 924, in parse
    result = builder.parseFile(fp)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 207, in parseFile
    parser.Parse(buffer, 0)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: unbound prefix: line 2, column 0
```

Comment: It seems that minidom can not accept nested `span`. Because when I change the second `span` to a `p` tag, minidom will not complain any more. Why not use `beautifulsoup` for xml parsing, it more convenient.

Comment: i use `beautifulsoup` to find and retrieve tag from website and write in   an xlm file and i use `minidom` to retrive value in `span` and it's work.but whith the `span` whith `sys:...` this is not work.i think than this is the realy probleme.not `minidom`

Comment: the magic keyword is `python xml colon`. Google it!

Comment: you can use lxml for xml manipulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shown XML isn't valid because it uses a namespace prefix (`sys`) but doesn't define it and the XML parser (`xml.dom.expatbuilder` module) chokes on that.  You would have to go straight to the `expatbuilder` in order to give its `parse()` function the argument to ignore namespaces.  And if you want to extract the text node in the *second* `<span>` your index is off by one:

```
from xml.dom import expatbuilder


def main():
    document = expatbuilder.parse('test.xml', False)
    node = document.getElementsByTagName('span')[1]
    print float(node.firstChild.data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```